# Need to understand the concept from a book

Tags: wcf

I am learning WCF using a book named "Window communication foundation 4: step by step". I the second chapter, there was a tutorial about developing windows service for WCF. The client communicates to the named pipe endpoint.

```
//WCF inside Windows service.
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    productsServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(ProductsServiceImpl));
    NetNamedPipeBinding binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding();
    productsServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IProductsService),
            binding, "net.pipe://localhost/ProductsServicePipe");
    productsServiceHost.Open();
}
```

And the client has an endpoint defined in App.config

```
<endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/ProductsServicePipe"
    binding="netNamedPipeBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
    contract="ProductsService.IProductsService"
    name="NetNamedPipeBinding_IProductsService" />
```

I need to create a proxy object to a "Service reference" which is not the windows service I mentioned earlier.

```
// Create a proxy object and connect to the service
// There service reference for "ProductsServiceClient" is
// "http://localhost:51397/ProductsService/Service.svc"
ProductsServiceClient proxy = new ProductsServiceClient("NetNamedPipeBinding_IProductsService");
```

Without "ProductsServiceClient", I could not initiate the proxy. Why do I need to that service reference, as I connect to a window service. I could not understand the concept clearly.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the term **service** is being used in two senses. You have the windows service which is the host for the WCF service. The reason that you had to create a service reference was so that your project could generate all off the code necessary to create a proxy to communicate with the WCF service. As an alternative to adding a service reference you could also have used a [Channel Factory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734681.aspx). The key thing to understand is that when you are creating a WCF service you generally access that service through the WCF pipeline (via a proxy or a channel factory), even if you are doing so from the project where it is defined.

If it is the case that you are unclear about how to generate a proxy for self hosted WCF service, you should look into how [svcutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702581.aspx) can used to generate proxies for compiled services.

Comment: If I host a wcf service in IIS, I could directly add service reference to my client. But I host it as a windows service, I could not add reference. I need to refer the original wcf to generate proxy. But the ChannelFactory example in the url, helps only if the wcf service exists in the same project. I have diff projects for client and host.

Comment: I added details above that should help.